# Jenkins groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property Bash

Tags: bash, jenkins, groovy

when running a Jenkins Groovy Piepline script that executes bash shell, a locally set variable can't be found when echo'ed out.

It reports error -

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: md5Value for class: WorkflowScript
```

Any ideas / pointer would be much appreciated.

```
#!groovy

node {

    try {

      stage('Test-Echo') {

          sh """
                #!/usr/bin/env bash

                md5Value='y'

                echo 'md5Value : ${md5Value}'

           """
       }

    } catch (e) {
        println (e.getMessage())
    }
}
```

## Reply to comment 1

Yes I've tried these different permutations, all report the same error.

```
echo 'md5Value : ${md5Value}'
echo "md5Value : ${md5Value}"
echo 'md5Value : ' ${md5Value}
echo "md5Value : " ${md5Value}
echo 'md5Value :  $md5Value'
echo 'md5Value : ' $md5Value
echo "md5Value :  $md5Value"
echo "md5Value : " $md5Value
```

If the exception is handled locally it produces error -

```
hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 1
```

## Reply to comment 2

By updating the variable to

```
echo 'md5Value : " \${md5Value}
```

It's now producing error

```
hudson.AbortException: script returned exit code 126 //: Permission denied
```

Comment: did you tried `$md5Value`?

Comment: The error message suggests that it is a groovy problem, not a bash one. Are you sure Jenkins interprets the script located in your `sh` block as a bash script ?

Comment: if you use doubel quotes Groovy will do string interpolation on literals prefixed with a $. For "md5Value : ${md5Value}" you will need a variable md5Value in Groovy. Just use single quotes:  'md5Value : ${md5Value}'. Also check the difference between GString and String in Groovy: https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_string_interpolation

Answer (score 0):

## Workaround

So the workaround is to put the bash shell into its own script and then the local variable assignment works as seen here -

```
#!groovy

node {

    try {

      stage('Test-Echo') {
          
        git poll: true,
          branch: "develop",
          credentialsId: 'xxx',
          url: 'https://yyy.org/here/and-there.git'

    
        sh """
            chmod +x ./jenkins/test/echo-test.sh
            
            ./jenkins/test/echo-test.sh
            
            exit "\${?}"
            
        """

       }
    } catch (e) {
        println (e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And the bash script

```
#!/bin/bash

md5Value="y"

echo "md5Value : ${md5Value}"
```

Answer (score 0):

change the triple double quote to single quote, and replace the single quote to double quote inside the script as following:

```
          sh '''
                #!/usr/bin/env bash

                md5Value='y'

                echo "md5Value : ${md5Value}"

           '''
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the workaround suggested on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/930312/jenkins-environment-variable-not-setting-up-from-pipeline) and it worked. Try

```
echo "md5Value : ${'$'}md5Value"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this works well.

```
sh """
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   md5Value='y'
   echo md5Value : \$md5Value
"""
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).